# Print translated Image field in node template

Tags: 8, nodes

```
$nodeObj = Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('node')->loadByProperties(['type' => 'books' ]);
```

$nodeObj has field 'field_book_image' and 'target_id' => string(2) "65"
in node preprocess we can get file URL
$file = File::load($target_id);

but is there any way I can print image field directly in node template with current language

```
{{ item.translation(langId).field_book_image.entity }}

{{item.field_book_image.entity.uri.value}}

{{ `file_url(node.field_book_image.entity.uri.value) }}`
```

but none of above giving Image path or Image value

Comment: If you are in node template you can just do like this `{{ content.field_book_image }}`.

Comment: @Jdrupal I'm in node template and for that node this is possible but for I m printing value for other nodes by doing query $nodeObj

Comment: Ok, if node is the other node you should be able to do it like this, `<img src="{{ file_url(node.field_book_image.entity.uri.value) }}">`.